# Word meaning "to put softy?"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I'm sure there are many words describing this but for some reason I can't think of an.

Like to use in an example like this:

> You feel as though you'd been **put softly** in the cradle of Mother
>   Nature.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Nestled* as in "You feel as though you'd been **nestled** in the cradle of Mother Nature."